# Eloquent resolve distant relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

let's say I've this kind of structure.

```
| lines      |   | products |   | orders |
|------------|   |----------|   |--------|
| id         |   | id       |   | id     |
| product_id |   |----------|   |--------|
| order_id   |
|------------|
```

Is there a way in Laravel Eloquent to load related products given an order? I've tried with `hasManyThrough(Product::class, Line::class)` with no luck, because on products table there's no reference to the order. Is there a method that can resolve this relationship or should I write a raw query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a many-to-many relationship in Order model:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','lines', 'order_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Then you can get products related to an order:

```
$order_id = 12;
$order = Order::find($order_id);
$order_products = $order->products;
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you MEDZ, I hadn't really thought about it.